# Which graph is "the right one"?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

When you plot f(x)=e^((-x)^2)
then Wolfram Alpha displays you this:

[image: Plot_from_WolframAlpha]

But Anaconda Spyder shows this:

[image: Plot_from_Anaconda_Spyder]

The code is:

```
import pylab as pyl
import numpy as nu
x = nu.linspace(-5,5,1000)
f = nu.exp(-x**2)
pyl.plot(x,f)
pyl.show()
```

The code is not the problem. I am just confused why I get 2 different graphs.
And which graph is now "the right one"?

Answer (score 5):

Note the difference between

```
numpy.exp(-x**2)     ## (1)
numpy.exp((-x)**2)   ## (2)
```

In wolfram alpha you plotted (2), in spyder you plotted (1)

Comment: Yes. Now I can see it. LOL Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two graphs depict different functions. You put f(x)=e^((-x)^2) in Wolfram Alpha, but f(x)=e^(-(x^2)) in Python. Be careful about your parentheses.

If you really meant f(x)=e^((-x)^2), then update your code to:

```
f = nu.exp((-x)**2)
```

Otherwise update your input into Wolfram Alpha to f(x)=e^(-(x^2)).